# Reference a server control using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm passing a server control name to a javascript function.

```
function SelectAllCheckboxes(chk, ctrlName) {
    alert(ctrlName);
```

The alert returns "gridPublishers"...

So...
Why does this work:

```
$("#MainContent_GridPublishers_gridPublishers").hide();
```

But this doesn't :

```
$("#MainContent_GridPublishers_" + ctrlName).hide();
```

also...

```
alert($("#MainContent_GridPublishers_" + ctrlName).length);
```

returns "0"

alert('T' + ctrlName + "T");
returns "TgridPublishersT"

```
console.log("#MainContent_GridPublishers_" + ctrlName);
```

returns "#MainContent_GridPublishers_GridPublishers "

Comment: It should work.. Did you try to alert `$("#MainContent_GridPublishers_" + ctrlName).length` or try `alert('T' + ctrlName)` to check leading space(s). My guess is, the ctrlName has a leading space which you missed it when you alerted it.

Comment: `console.log("#MainContent_GridPublishers_" + ctrlName)` is your friend.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've updated my question with the results to your suggestions

Comment: Something isn't right here. How does `alert(ctrlName)` return `gridPublishers` and the `console.log` returns `GridPublishers` (notice the uppercase G)

Comment: @MattR - Thanks buddy !!  You are an eagle-eyed star !!!

Comment: looks liek a scope issue to me. The variable ctrlName is created in the SelectAllCheckboxes function, so if you are trying to access ctrlName outside of that function it's not going to work as written( so far I only see partial examples here...)

Comment: @DanielWard - thanks for the reply mate, but MattR spotted my problem. Capitilization ! (How embarrassing!)  FYI - all the aove lines of code were within the function SelectAllCheckboxes, I was simply using JQuery.hide to illustrate the problem. Thanks again for trying to help though.